# Suspicious redirect in Chrome

Tags: malware, virus, url-redirection, spyware

I was online and one of the sites randomly redirected to a site called mcafeesecurity.application-center.club.  It was talking about how my mcafee has expired (my subscription is current). I scanned my computer with malwarebytes and mcafee (both full scans and nothing was found).  Does anyone have any idea what this is?  I know it is a scam site, but I need to know the type of virus/malware/phishing attempt I am dealing with.

Comment: Was it an http website that got redirected?

Comment: What extension have you recently installed?

Comment: It was an http site that was redirected, and I haven’t installed any extensions.  I was trying to go to a cooking website and it redirected.  However, I did run adwcleaner and I think it solved the issue (two PUPs were found PUP.Optional.Legacy for Ask and AOL were found under Chromium URLs).  But I had a feeling it was an adware situation

Answer (score 2):

Mcafeesecurity.application-center.club is a browser redirect program presented as something that it’s not – an enhanced search engine that’s better than products offered by established names. It may certainly seem great on the surface – you’re provided with local weather, news, quick access to iHeartRadio, YouTube, SoundCloud, Amazon, Gmail, Yahoo!, Twitter, Instagram, and, of course, an ability to search the Web for information. The application is completely free, so installing it may seem appealing, but you shouldn’t trust it and, as a matter of fact, should keep it as far away from the system as possible.

http://pcfixguides.com/best-method-to-remove-mcafeesecurity-application-center-club/